# the output type “SVF2” doesn’t exist in the java library “forge java sdk”

Tags: java, autodesk-forge

I'm coding with Java language ( Spring Boot framework ) and I'm using “forge java sdk” dependency (version 1.0.2)

[forge java sdk dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnyeI.png)

I want to translate a '.rvt' file to SVF2 format but I can’t find this output type in the forge library.

[Forge library piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie13Q.png)

So in this case , I can’t set “SVF2” format. How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that SDK does not have that option yet. I would suggest using direct REST requests.